# Python code not displaying graph

Tags: python, visualization

I am using some python code from kaggle that plots a bar graph. However, when I run it, it does not display the graph. When I run it in the IDE I get the following output:

`<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x1200b9ba8> 
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x1200b9ba8>
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x1200b9ba8>`

I have used the `.show()` method but nothing seems to work.

Here is the link to the code that I am using:

[Code](https://opendata.socrata.com/Government/Airplane-Crashes-and-Fatalities-Since-1908/q2te-8cvq)

I also have it directly in the question:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# Input data files are available in the "../input/" directory.
# For example, running this (by clicking run or pressing Shift+Enter) will list the files in the input directory

#from subprocess import check_output
#print(check_output(["ls", "../input"]).decode("utf8"))

# Any results you write to the current directory are saved as output.

frame=pd.read_csv('Project_Airplane_Crashes_and_Fatalities_Since_1908.csv',sep=',')
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12.0, 8.0)

operator = frame[['Operator','Fatalities']].groupby('Operator').agg(['sum','count'])

fig_ops,((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4))=plt.subplots(2,2,sharex=True)
accidents = operator['Fatalities','count'].sort_values(ascending=False)
totalacc = accidents.sum()
accprop = accidents/totalacc
accidents.head(10).plot(kind='bar',title='Accidents by Operator',ax=ax1,grid=True,rot=90)
accprop.head(10).plot(kind='bar',title='Proportion of Total Accidents',ax=ax2,grid=True,rot=90)

fatalities = operator['Fatalities','sum'].sort_values(ascending=False)
fatalities.head(10).plot(kind='bar',title='Fatalities by Operator',ax=ax3,grid=True,rot=90)
totalfatal = fatalities.sum()
fatalprop = fatalities/totalfatal
#print(fatalprop)
fatalprop.head(10).plot(kind='bar',title='Proportion of total Fatalities',ax=ax4,grid=True,rot=90)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please learn to format your questions. https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 1):

I have gotten the answer to my question since I keep searching for solution.
I got the solution here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534453/matplotlib-does-not-show-my-drawings-although-i-call-pyplot-show)

By StefanM

So all I needed and should have done is to simply do 
plt.show()
and I was typing fatalprop.head(10).show()
Thank you